# Openvpn and ssh which port can be accessed

Tags: ssh, openvpn

Scenario:

- point to point openvpn between two machines (this implies that computerA and computerB have both public ip)

If I nmap computerA (nmap -PO 192.168.0.10) the output shows that there are 22 and 443 open ports only.
ComputerA's public ip is natted.
Other machines belonging to the same LAN have the same public ip.

In a nutshell:

```
-computerA private ip: 192.168.0.10 

-computerA public ip: 169.159.65.97

-computerC (same LAN as computerA) private ip: 192.168.0.12

-computerC public ip: 169.159.65.97

-computerD (same LAN as computerA) private ip: 192.168.0.25

-computerD public ip: 169.159.65.97
```

My understanding is that if I want to connect to computerA from computerB (different LAN far away from computerA) through vpn using ssh I should know computerA open ports..right?

But as I stated before port 22 is open...but if I try to ssh to 169.159.65.97 I get no access.
Am I right in saying that probably computerA is accessible through ssh using a different port? But which one?...

Thanks

Comment: For me it's a little bit unclear what network topology do you have. I do not see computerB details. Also where are computerC and cumputerD? 
If servers A and B are connected with PtP using tun you can access A from B using tun IP. What is private IP? Is it IP used in VPN or not? It would easier if you include ifconfig output.

Comment: The vpn is betwen computerA and computerB only. computerA belongs to the LAN whose address (private) is: 192.168.0.0-255. computerB belongs to the LAN whose address (private) is: 192.168.99.0-255 (so different subnet..)

Comment: What type of device do you use? Tap/tun?

Answer (score 0):

Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) uses TCP port 443. This is used for your VPN connection.
SSH is on port 22.
If you want to do SSH through machine 1 to another machine (2) you can use machine 1 as tunnel, if you run:

```
ssh myaccount@machine1 -L 2222:machine2:22 -g
```

although if you're not in same net with machine 2, but machine 1, you can connect to machine2 with:

```
ssh myaccount@machine2 -p 2222
```

so you redirected port 22.